# Making a clock in Antlr

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm making a datatype in Antlr called time, which will return a clock of the form Hour:Minute

This is what my code looks like so far:

```
grammar clock;
clock: HOUR ':' MINUTE

HOUR: '2'[0-3]|'1'[0-9]|[0-9];

MINUTE: [0-5][0-9]
```

Our code fails to recognize the "HOUR" portion, and it recognizes minute.  I even changed HOUR to be the same value as minute, and it still fails to recognize HOUR.  To check if our regex was wrong, we even swapped HOUR and MINUTE in the order, and did MINUTE:HOUR, and it recognized hour, but not minute.  Is there something I'm missing?  What's going on that it will never parse HOUR, but always MINUTE?

Answer (score 2):

ANTLR lexers fully assign unambiguous token types before the parser is ever used. When multiple token types can match a token, the first one appearing in the grammar is the one that is used. For your grammar, a token cannot have the type `HOUR` and the type `MINUTE` at the same time. Since the input `12` matches both of these lexer rules, the first appearing in the grammar is used so `12` will *always* be an `HOUR` and *never* be a `MINUTE`.

Typically lexers produce integers similar to the following rule:

```
INT : [0-9]+;
```

Then a parser rule for `clock` might look like this:

```
clock : INT ':' INT;
```

Since you are using ANTLR 4, you can extend the generated class `ClockBaseListener` and override the `enterClock` method to perform additional validation (specifically, validating that the first `INT` meets the hour requirements and the second `INT` meets the minute requirements.